# Access to a text before a node with xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have an html text like this

```
<span class="item-detail">2 <small>hab.</small></span>                                  
<span class="item-detail">64 <small>m²</small></span>
<span class="item-detail">Planta 3ª <small>exterior con ascensor</small></span>
```

Which is the best way to select the 64 (which is the number of meters), taking into account that the order of the elements may vary

Comment: All of those tags have the same attribute values. How are you supposed to determine that "64" is the correct element?  Are you explicitly  looking for 64?  So you always want the prior element regardless of order?

Comment: @OldProgrammer. We can know that is the element because the text before "<small>m²</small>" is always the number of meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not 100% certain of the requirement, but try this:

```
//span[small/text()="m²"]/text()[1]
```

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: please accept answer if you feel this is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can use below x-path

```
.//span[@class='item-detail' and child::small[contains(.,'m²')]]/text()[1]
```